# Subida ficheros a FTP con un .bat

Tags: windows, ftp

Estoy intentando buscar información de como realizar un .bat que se conecte a un servidor1 y de ahí que se conecte a un servidor FTP y entre ellos pasar datos.

(Solamente quiero subir carpetas desde el servidor1 al servidor FTP)

He estado buscando bastante información y no hay gran cosa acerca de subir carpetas completas a un servidor FTP.

También he visto que tendría que autoinciar la sesión, es decir que el .bat llevara la contraseña y usuario, he visto por diferentes paginas que esa parte la suelen meter en un .txt y lo llaman desde el .bat

NO lo entiendo muy bien, si me podríais explicar con algún ejemplo os lo agradecería muchísimo. Trabajo con w10 y el FTP se aloja en un Synology.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo hasta ahora?

Comment: El directorio tiene subdirectorios dentro? O únicamente ficheros?

Comment: Buenas, si he estado intentando te paso una parte del codigo. (No tengo mucha idea de como hacerlo lo siento por mi torpeza )                             
# Conectamos al servidor
ftp 63.25.179.165
user: admin
pass: xxxx                                                                                                           cd /Temp
put test.txt
bye                                                                                                                      No se se si asi se haria o no, lo he probrado y no me funciona. Gracias

Comment: Buenas, si tiene subdirectorios y un monton de archivos.

Comment: Los subdirectorios son siempre los mismos? Misma cantidad y nombre? O van variando y no se puede saber de antemano el nombre de los mismos? Por ejemplo: Si procesas una ruta "ruta_uno" podría tener de subdirectorios "sub1" y "sub2", y si ahora procesas "ruta_dos", también tendría "sub1" y "sub2"? o podría ser cualquier otra cosa?

Comment: EL nombre de las carpetas siempre van a ser lo mismo en un principio no camban a noser que se añadan alguna o se elimine, lo unico que los archivos que hay en su interior van a ir modificándose. Hay una cosa que no se si se puede hacer yo tengo por ejemplo una carpeta llamada PRUEBA y dentro de PRUEBA entro otra carpeta llamada BACKUPS y dentro varias carpetas. Podria subir directamente la carpeta PRUEBA al FTP ¿?.

Comment: No, el comando ftp no trabaja con subcarpetas. De ahí mi anterior pregunta. La dificultad para una respuesta dependerá de cuál es la estructura de la carpetas que hay dentro. Si la estructura es la misma (siempre los mismos subdirectorios), será más fácil. Si los subdirectorios pueden ir variando, se complicará.

Comment: Si, en un principio siempre van a ser los mismos subdirectorios